# Suspended accounts effect badges(plural) like Fanatic?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, account-suspension

When I get suspended do I still get credited for visiting everyday? an what of the other badges?(in the title it don't limit this only to fanatic) Are there badges that are negatively effected?

Comment: from the dupe: *Badges can still be earned and awarded.*

Comment: You are asking a completely new question. Please don't edit an old question into a new one - ask a new question.

Comment: @Catija I would love to asked a new question but all I am allowed to do critique current ones.

Comment: but if you somehow managed to get qbanned, editing it to a completely different question after people have answered... seems kind of a less than nice thing to do

Comment: @JourneymanGeek can you lift my qban?

Comment: Nope. Even on a site where I have moddy powers. Its automatic. I suppose you can wait for your 6 monthly grace period and... not mess it up?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek by making edits can i extend my grace period?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek suspension times are just to extreme for low quality questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The badge works for just visiting the main page of a site, and that is okay: if you go through the main site and nothing interests you, it still counts as visiting the site.

Hence, suspended users should be able to maintain their consecutive day count through a suspension and earn that badge.